# Storing file input ID inside variable during for loop | PHP

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, for-loop

I am using the following HTML & PHP code to move multiple images to my server.

**Is there a way using my code that I can associate a specific input element with the uploaded file?**

So in my **for loop**, I can discover when the image from '**image_22**' is being processed. Is this possible using my current code?

Dream world would be storing the value **"image_22"** inside a variable **$imageNum** :-)

Here is a snippet of what I'm currently working with...

**HTML:**

```
<input id="image_22" name="images[]" type="file"  />
<input id="image_8" name="images[]" type="file"  />  
...
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $number_of_file_fields = 0;
    $number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
    $number_of_moved_files = 0;
    $uploaded_files = array();
    $upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/uploaded/'; //set upload directory


    /**
     * we get a $_FILES['images'] array ,
     * we procee this array while iterating with simple for loop
     * you can check this array by print_r($_FILES['images']);
     */
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++) {
        $number_of_file_fields++;
        if ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != '') { //check if file field empty or not
            $number_of_uploaded_files++;
            $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory . 
    $_FILES['images']['name'][$i])) {
                $number_of_moved_files++;
            }

        }

    }
    echo "Number of File fields created $number_of_file_fields.<br/> ";
    echo "Number of files submitted $number_of_uploaded_files . <br/>";
    echo "Number of successfully moved files $number_of_moved_files . <br/>";
    echo "File Names are <br/>" . implode(',', $uploaded_files);
    }
    ?>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your HTML, just include that value inside the `[]`.

```
<input id="image_22" name="images[22]" type="file"  />
<input id="image_8" name="images[8]" type="file"  />
```

In your loop, instead of an incremental for loop, use a `foreach` with index, which is a more common pattern in PHP than the incremental type. The `$index` will be the number supplied in the `[]`:

```
// Loop over the ['name'] key in $_FILES['images'] to get all the named indexes
foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $index => $filename) {

  if ($filename != '') {
     // not empty...
     $number_of_uploaded_files++;

     // Check for validity (see below)...

     // Use the name concatenated with _$index to supply store the index with the filename
     $uploaded_files[] = $filename . "_$index";
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$index], $upload_directory . $filename . "_$index")) {
       // successful rename
       $number_of_moved_files++;
     }
  }
}
```

Note that your script is currently vulnerable to path injection attacks.  You must filter the `name` of each file against the inclusion of things like `../` which could force the file to be saved anywhere on your filesystem (writable by the web server)!  It is recommended to check the name with a regular expression of acceptable values:

```
// Verify that the uploaded filename contains only letters, numbers, hyphen, underscore, space before the `.` and letters only after the `.`
// You could also insist that it end in `.(jpg|gif|png)` or whatever your acceptable formats are
// Most important is to prevent things like `../`
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_- ]+\.[a-z]+$/i', $filename)) {
  // It's an ok filename
}
```

Comment: In addition, using javascript you are able to change the name attribute to be associated with the id attribute. In other word, extracting the trailing number of the id and make it as index for the name.

Comment: Many thanks for such a speedy response. Out of interest, would it confuse my for loop if I added the numbers inside the square brackets?

Comment: Great point on the injection attack too - I'll get onto fixing it shortly. Fortunately, we're still in development phase :)

Comment: Perfect, other Michael ;-) I'll try this shortly & report back.

Comment: Just my luck, our server is down. I'll report back when tested. Sorry :-/

Comment: **UPDATE** It seems to bypass this `if ($fileinfo['name'] != '') {` even though I definitely upload images. Strange?

Comment: `array(3) { [9]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(21) "football_logo_panel.png" } array(3) { [9]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(9) "image/png" } array(3) { [9]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpHWWwnW" } array(3) { [9]=> int(4) [11]=> int(4) [12]=> int(0) } array(3) { [9]=> int(0) [11]=> int(0) [12]=> int(14697) }`

Comment: Will do. Thanks again for your help here. Do you want to move to chat? I'm not fussed :)

Comment: Ah wait I get it -- `$_FILES` when submitted as an array `[]` does not structure itself the way I thought it did.  Update forthcoming above, hang on...

Comment: Wow - brilliant!! Sorry for the 40minute delay getting back to you - was getting dinner :) Also sorry for not posting dump correctly :/ Will test now.

Comment: Quick question: Do I change this: `$uploaded_files[] = $fileinfo['images']['name'][$i];    
   $filename = $dir."/uploaded/".$fileinfo['images']['name'][$i];` ?

Comment: Instead of `$i`, it is `$index` in this loop.  and in the loop, `$filename` refers to the same value as `$_FILES['images']['name'][$index]`

Comment: Great stuff - you are very patient - sorry for the n00bish nature of this query. brb

Comment: Guys, please take the real time stuff to chat.  If this is clarifying the question or an answer, please edit the question and answer with the information. As it stands now, it just appears like you two are going through a live debugging session. Stack Overflow comments are not a good place for that.  I'll be going through and purging these comments shortly, so please move any information you want to keep to the appropriate place.